# Printing names in tabular format using puts in for loop, but only last name is printed correctly

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop, struct

Create a structure to specify the data for customers in a bank. The data to be stored is: Account number, Name, Balance in account. Assume a maximum of 200 customers in the bank.

```
struct CustomerData {
   int   acNum;
   float balance;
   char name[];
} n[2];

void main() {
    for(int i = 0;i<2; i++) {
        printf("give Ac. no. of %d customer\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&n[i].acNum);
        printf("balance of customer %d\n",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&n[i].balance);
        printf("Name of customer %d\n",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(n[i].name);
    }

    printf(" Name      Acc. no    Balance \n");

    for(int i =0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("%c      %d           %f\n",puts(n[i].name),n[i].acNum,n[i].balance);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
give Ac. no. of 1 customer
50054
balance of customer 1
11316
Name of customer 1
sahil
give Ac. no. of 2 customer
15655
balance of customer 2
100
Name of customer 2
Rishav
 Name      Acc. no    Balance
'=
       50054           11316.000000
Rishav
       15655           100.000000

Process returned 34 (0x22)   execution time : 25.120 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: `fflush` on input streams invokes undefined behavior, and `gets(n[i].name);` is not only wrong because it's using a function no longer in the standard library, it's worse because it's targeting a flexible array member that has no "there" there. Whatever book/site is teaching this, burn it.

Comment: Why do you print the result of `puts`? It seems you have missed some crucial parts of the early chapters of your beginners text-book. And if you don't have a book, please get one.

Comment: And [the flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) `name` in your structure isn't a dynamic array. There's no space allocated for it. You really need to get a hold of a decent beginners book and start reading it from the very beginning. And whatever resource you currently use to learn C, throw it away.

Comment: Sahil Dadhwal, what is the longest name allowed?  [600+ letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.)?

Comment: Sahil Dadhwal, I recommend to drop `scanf()`.  Use `fgets()` to read each line of user input into a string and then parse the string.

Comment: You're supposed to allow up to 200 customers; your code insists on exactly 2 and would (probably) crash if any more were added.  Also, consistent indentation is a great help to everyone — especially people learning to read C code.  See also [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/15168)

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the comments, there are a couple of problems in your code:

1. Never do `fflush(stdin)`. It causes an undefined behaviour.
2. Never use `scanf()` to read input. Use `fgets()` instead.
3. You should indent your code properly so it becomes easier to read.

---

Here is a better version of your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for strcspn()

struct CustomerData {
    int acNum;
    float balance;
    char name[255]; // Give it a size
};
```

We need to define a function that reads one line from the input (remember not to use `scanf()`):

```c
char *readstr(char *str, int size)
{
    if (!fgets(str, size, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; // fgets() reads the ending '\n' so null-terminate the string
    return str;
}
```

You can do the same with `int`s and `float`s:

```c
int readint(int *i)
{
    char buffer[255];
    if (!fgets(buffer, 255, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error\n");
        return 0; // failed
    }

    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", i) != 1)
        return 0; // failed
    
    return 1; // success
}

int readfloat(float *f)
{
    char buffer[255];
    if (!fgets(buffer, 255, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error\n");
        return 0; // failed
    }

    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%f", f) != 1)
        return 0; // failed
        
    return 1; // success
}
```

Now, you can use those functions in your `main()`:

```c
int main() // main() should always return an int
{
    const int num_customers = 2; // In case you wanted to change it later
    struct CustomerData n[num_customers];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num_customers; i++) {
        printf("give Ac. no. of %d customer: ", i+1);
        readint(&n[i].acNum);
        
        printf("balance of customer %d: ", i+1);
        readfloat(&n[i].balance);
        
        printf("Name of customer %d: ", i+1);
        readstr(n[i].name, sizeof(n[i].name));
    }
    
    printf("\nName\tAcc. no\tBalance\n");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num_customers; i++)
        printf("%s\t%d\t%f\n", n[i].name, n[i].acNum, n[i].balance);
}
```

An example output:

```
give Ac. no. of 1 customer: 1
balance of customer 1: 12
Name of customer 1: john
give Ac. no. of 2 customer: 2
balance of customer 2: 65.5
Name of customer 2: wick

Name    Acc. no Balance
john    1       12.000000
wick    2       65.500000
```